# How can I use Stripe Card Reader M2 using Javascript or Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I would like to know if there is any repository or any demo app based on JS/IONIC/ANGULAR to use Stripe Card Reader M2. I don't want to build a native app based on Java and Swift to use that terminal. So I don't know if there is any posibility to get the card data from the reader using JS and Bluetooth with Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

There's no official Ionic library but there's a react-native library that you can use to build your Terminal application in JS

https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/setup-integration?terminal-sdk-platform=react-native

Comment: Do you know any third party solution to make the app?